# Script Times Out - getFileById(id)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to run a script in GoogleSheet, a script which worked for a long time as expected. But all of a sudden, it times out.

When I debug the script, it seems to hang on this part:

```
function returnParentFolder()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var fileId = ss.getId();
  **var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);**

  theParentFolder = file.getParents().next();
  return theParentFolder;
}
```

There seems no return on the bold function, (the File variable won't be filled)
The script won't continue either after this function, and after a while it's time out.

What could be the problem, or the solution?

Comment: Have you looked at the Execution transcript in the View menu? It logs every step and you can see if it's throwing an error.

Comment: When I take a look at the transcript, I see more or less the same conclusion: [17-10-03 07:32:50:263 PDT] DriveApp.getFileById([xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]) [544.964 seconds] (x's replaced by the correct hash of course)

Comment: I can't replicate the error. Some others reported issues of unexpected server errors in scripts yesterday. I'd say keep an eye on it over the day and see if it works itself out. There's nothing wrong with this block of code, though.

Answer (score 0):

As of this posting, everything seems to be working fine if you run it from the script editor (Tools -> Script Editor) and not directly from `script.google.com`

```
function returnParentFolder()

    {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var fileId = ss.getId();
      var file = DriveApp.getFileById('MY_FILE_ID');
    
      theParentFolder = file.getParents().next();
      Logger.log(theParentFolder);
      return theParentFolder;
    }
```

and got a successful result in the logs.

If you're still experiencing this error try this solution form this [google forum](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/67054694):

In `script.google.com`:

1. Resources -> Advance Google Services
2. Enable Drive API
   [image]
3. You will be asked to enable it in the Google Dev console. Click the link and enable Drive API.